# Reasoning behind the resolution of partial fractions when denominator is the product of linear factors where some of them are repeating

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions, rational-functions

The following text is from *Mathematics for Class XII by Dr. R.D.Sharma*, chapter "Indefinite Integrals", topic "Integration of Rational Algebraic Functions by using Partial Fractions", sub topic "Case II: When the denominator $g(x)$ [in $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$] is expressible as the product of the linear factors such that some of them are repeating.":

> Let $g(x)=(x-a)^k(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\dots(x-a_r).$ Then we assume that
>
> $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{A_1}{x-a}+\frac{A_2}{(x-a)^2}+\frac{A_3}{(x-a)^3}+\dots+\frac{A_k}{(x-a)^k}+\frac{B_1}{x-a_1}+\frac{B_2}{x-a_2}+\dots+\frac{B_r}{x-a_r}$$
>
> i.e., corresponding to non-repeating factors we assume as in Case I [When denominator is expressible as the product of non-repeating linear factors] and for each repeating factor $(x-a)^k$, we assume partial fractions
>
> $$\frac{A_1}{x-a}+\frac{A_2}{(x-a)^2}+\frac{A_3}{(x-a)^3}+\dots+\frac{A_k}{(x-a)^k}$$
>
> where $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_k$ are constants.

What is the reasoning behind this particular choice of partial fractions in this case? Why do we want to consider all positive integral powers of $(x-a)$ upto $k$? What if we assume the partial fraction with only the first term $\frac{A_1}{x-a}$ like Case I? Why not consider only the first and last terms in the given partial fraction expression? I think it'll save a lot of time. Will any essential data will be lost as we neglect the rest of the terms in the expression?

Comment: Without these terms, a partial fraction decomposition will generally not be possible (try out a few examples). The (rough) underlying reason is that this general form contains enough polynomials to form a basis of a certain polynomial space. The reason why we use these polynomial denominators instead of just any is because they are related to the original denominator, not only making the proof canonical, but also their computation.

Comment: Try reading up on "abstract vector spaces", and think about the special case where vectors are polynomial functions, paying special attention to the concept of "linear independence.". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you need the higher order terms because without them you do not have enough flexibility to write an expansion you can integrate.

For example, how you would you express
$$
\frac{1}{x^2 (x-1)}
$$
in the form
$$
\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x-1} ?
$$

When you clear fractions and try to solve for the constants the polynomial degrees don't match.

If you tried the form 
$$
\frac{A}{x^2} + \frac{B}{x-1}  
$$
you would have the right denominator but not enough freedom to match the coefficients in the numerator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the main reasons for this choice are matching the degree of denominator on either sides, and having enough equations to obtain the constants. Am I right?

Comment: @M.GuruVishnu Yes.